# Chrome/mium & Brave browser does not recognize any other .locahost subdomain in an Ip ouside 127.0.0.1

Tags: google-chrome, localhost, chromium, hosts, brave

As seen in this [question](https://superuser.com/q/1447767/860667) google chrome and any cromium-based browser (Brave Browser, Chromium) will enforce any `.localhost` subdomain to be in 127.0.0.1 and it will ingore any entry in `/etc/hosts` file.

But on my team the convention is to use `.localhost` subdomains pointing to a `vagrant` running vms that are not `127.0.0.1` therefore that makes the whole workflow breaking into the heterogenous team (each member has a different os to his computer)

How I can bypass this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to bypass this problem is to have a local per workstation/employer reverse proxy listening into `127.0.0.1` and any port you use to communicate with the in-development applications.

A simple way to do that is utilizing the `nginx` webserver. Assuming that the `.localhost` subdomain is the `myapp.localhost` and the vagrant vm listens into the ip `192.168.10.80`, the correct nginx settings is:

```
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name myapp.localhost;
 location / {
    proxy_set_header Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://192.168.10.80;
 }
}
```

In ubuntu GNU/Linux distro you should remove the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` create a new file into `/etc/nginx/sites-available` and symlink into `etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` folder.

> **NOTE:** Use full paths during symlinking instead of relative ones.

Also as you noticed I also pass the headers `Host` and `X-Forwarded-For` that is used because some applications may resolves the url from headers, and the `Host` header is the one usually used (eg. Ancient versions of Codeingiter) to autoresolve the url when in development.

Also for other frameworks may also stop serving content due to lack of the appropriate headers as well, making development PITA (the other one that is not used in souvlaki ;) ).